# vcgencmd not found

Tags: pi-4, python-3, ubuntu, 64-bit

Recently, i installed ubuntu server 20 64bit on Raspberry pi 4 B+ 4GB model, and youtube is laggy
so i searched a bit and installed raspi-config and tried to change memory split setting
but it says i don't have vcgencmd installed
I tried many things to install vcgencmd
i tried building userland, i succeed to build it, and i see vcgencmd is in /opt/vc/bin, but when i use

```
$ /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd
```

it says it can't find vcgencmd
I'm sure that there wasn't any typo, because i used tab auto correction
i also tried installing libraspberrypi-bin, but it says it is not available
i tried

```
pip3 install vcgencmd
```

it installed successfuly, but when i try to use it, it says

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/vcgencmd/**init**.py", line
>   20, in 
>       subprocess.check_output('vcgencmd')   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
>       return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
>       with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in **init**
>       self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'vcgencmd'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
>       mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 143, in _get_module_details
>       return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
>       **import**(pkg_name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/vcgencmd/**init**.py", line
>   22, in 
>       raise ImportError('\'vcgencmd\' does not exist in path') ImportError: 'vcgencmd' does not exist in path
>   i used raspi-update to update firmware, and there was no problem updating firmware
>   but i still can't use vcgencmd
>   can anyone help me?

Comment: I installed ubuntu-desktop on ubuntu server, since there isn't any desktop ubuntu 20 for raspberry pi 4 right now

Comment: What's the output of `ldd /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd`?

Comment: You need to add `/opt/vc/bin` to `$PATH`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)

Comment: output of ldd /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd is "it's not dynamic executable file" I use different language setting, so text could be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here: 1. `vcgencmd` cannot find its shared libraries, and 2. the Python module you're using cannot find the `vcgencmd` executable.

---

There are two possible solutions to the first problem:

A. Set the `rpath` of `vcgencmd` when building the Userland project:

```
cmake \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/opt/vc" \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH='${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib' \
    <your usual options>
```

B. Add `/opt/vc/lib` to the path of the dynamic linker/loader:

```sh
echo '/opt/vc/lib' | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/vc.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

---

The second problem is that the folder `/opt/vc/bin` is not in your `PATH`. There are many possible solutions, but you probably want to add it to the system-wide path:

```sh
echo 'export PATH="/opt/vc/bin:$PATH"' | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/vc.sh
```

Afterwards, reboot, or execute the command `export PATH="/opt/vc/bin:$PATH"` in the shell you're starting the Python program from.

Comment: I did both, but i still have problems, when i use vcgencmd, now it says it can't find "/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd: error while loading shared libraries: libvchiq_arm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" and i still get same issue on python

Comment: My Cmake options are -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/opt/vc" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH='${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib' -DARM64=ON

Comment: Sorry, i did something wrong, and it's working fine, Thanks!

Comment: This is it. Just added a ../bin to PATH and a ../lib to LDCONFIG and everything worked OK